# Tipue Search (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, livesearch

I'm trying to customize a [Tipue search](http://www.tipue.com/search/) script.

Currently the script is searching the entire HTML file (including metadata) and triggering false positives on the search results.  I'd like to eliminate the metadata from the critera or only allow the script to search a specific DIV (i.e. #pagewrap).

Here is a link to the current script:
http://www.worldonecommunications.com/ndrill/tipuesearch/tipuesearch.js
(Lines 37-77)

The pages are being indexed in a separate file, but I think the problem lies in the file listed above.

Comment: can you provide some examples of the error you mention?

Comment: It's not really an error.  The script itself is functioning, just not as I need it to.The meta keywords on each page are the same throughout the site (say a keyword = widget).  If I search for "widget", it hits on the meta keyword and returns every page on the server.  I'd like it only to search the body of an HTML page or within a specific DIV such as #pagewrap.

Comment: tipue project looks dead - github repo gone and site no longer exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who are interested:
The developer finally updated the search script to target only a specific DIV.  The updated code can be downloaded from their site:
http://www.tipue.com/search/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change these lines:

```
var t_1 = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('<title>');
var t_2 = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('</title>', t_1 + 7);
...
var t_1 = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('<meta name="description"');
var t_2 = html.toLowerCase().indexOf('"', t_1 + 34);
```

I'am also searching a way how to modify this engine to out results from page body.